# Communication Arduino Mega 2560 to PC failure/ hang up

Tags: logging, usb, arduino, communication, uart

we have a project where we use an Arduino Mega 2560 for datalogging. The arduino sends 
periodically (2s cycle) a string containing different sensor values. On the PC (Windows 7 and Windows XP) we use logview 
for visualization (www.logview.info/) which works well for our purposes. 
The stringformat
for logview is described here: http://www.logview.info/cms/d_formatbeschreibung.phtml

Our problem is that logview hangs up from time to time. The serial logging stops and logview can't
open the COM-Port anymore. The only solution is to unplug and reconnect the USB-cable. Unfortunately, this
isn't an acceptable solution for us.

What we have tried so far:

- We removed all sensors/actors from the Arduino Mega 2560 and sent only dummy strings over USB -> logview still hangs up
- We reduced the baudrate --> it seems, that the device doesn't hangs up so often (but still hangs up)
- We used shorter USB-cables --> it seems, that the device doesn't hangs up so often (but still hangs up)
- We used on the PC a simple PC-program writing serial data to a file (instead of logview) --> also hangs up
- We connected an additional arduino UsART/USB converter to the second USART from the Arduino and sent the same strings over both UARTS. On PC we watched both ports with logview and putty -> both hanged up

You have any idea? We think that it could be

- problem with ground
- problem with windows

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to calculate the difference-error on your baudrate on both systems, pc and arduino. Maybe the error is to high and integrated controll-functions return a failure status and let collaps the program

Comment: How can i measure the diffence-error? With an Oscilloscope the UART Signals ??

Comment: You can't measure it, you have to calculate it. Try it with this: BAUD = F_CPU/(16*(UBBRn+1))

if the difference is greater then 5% you have to choose another baudrate